# Confusion about Internal linkage

Tags: c++

According to the definition of internal linkage that i have read everywhere states that internal linkage means object is visible at file scope or everywhere in same file.

```
int main()
{
    extern int i;
    i = 0; //linker error
}

static int i;
```

Would you have it any way to make `i` visible inside, if its declared after main() without defining before it?

Comment: I doubt the problem you're **really** having is regarding the declaration of an `int`.  Can you elaborate on the real problem?

Answer (score 1):

This is not a linking problem, but a compilation problem. At the time your `main` is compiled, `i` is not yet declared. So you have to put `i` before your `main` function in order to compile it.

Comment: Even if i put `extern int i` before it, it still wont link. updated.

Comment: I'm not sure what an `extern` should help. Why don't you just put the declaration of `i` before your `main` and be done with it?

Comment: That would defeat the purpose of asking the question about internal linkage.

Answer (score 1):

You're confusing several issues.  First, "linkage" concerns symbols, not objects.  And secondly, independently of linkage, a symbol must be declared before you can use it.  Put the `static int i` before main, and there will be no problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution doesn't work as `extern` says that the variable is globally visible, but `static` says that it is not.

Presumably the linker believes this to be two different variables, and gets confused.

You *have* to declare all objects before use, but you also have to be consistent.